Navigating to other apps using 'Linking' in React Native
I have two apps. One is made in ReactNative and the other is a Unity3D app.
I have set up the React Native app to run deep links and the Unity3D app to receive deep links. (AndroidManifest.xml)
For the Unity3D app, I tried the following command and found that it worked fine.
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "miniAppOne://openApp?jvsioafjiofj" <package name>
However, when I tried to launch the Unity3D app using the deep link URL (miniAppOne://openApp?jvsioafjiofj) in React Native, it didn't work with the error message below. I used React Native's 'Linking.openURL(deeplink)' when using the deep link.
Error: Could not open URL 'miniAppOne://openApp?jvsioafjiofj': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=miniAppOne://openApp?jvsioafjiofj flg=0x10000000 }
How can I run a Unity3D app as a deep link in React Native?
Deep link code in the React Native app:
  const url:string = "miniAppOne://openApp?jvsioafjiofj";  // deeplink
  const appstoreUrl:string = "";  // alterUrl
  const playstoreUrl:string = "";  // alterUrl

  const deepLinkOpenApp1 = useCallback(async (url: string, alterUrl: string) => {
    const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
    console.log('Open App - URL: ', url);

    if (supported) {
      console.log('Open App - Supported');
      Linking.openURL(url).then(() => {
        console.log('Open App - Success');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Open App - Error: ', err);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Open App - Not Supported');
      Linking.openURL(alterUrl).then(() => {
        console.log('Open App - Success');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Open App - Error: ', err);
      });
    }
  }, []);

AndroidManifest.xml from the Unity3D app:
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="miniAppOne" android:host="openApp" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>

